# Can I play Minecraft on my Xbox One with someone on a 360?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I bought Minecraft for my Xbox 360 so my kid could play. I am going to get an Xbox One Minecraft edition. Can I play with her on Xbox live?

Comment: the short answer: yes

Comment: Good question. @padfoot if you want to answer the question, why not put in an official answer below?

Comment: @Mr________ my answer would be too short for a formal answer, i would just say yes... This is why i said: "***The Short Answer*** is yes"

Comment: Ok I see @padfoot

Answer (score 1):

Yes. These articles reference cross compatibility of the XBox One and XBox 360 respectively:

- [Minecraft’s cross-platform update is now available on Xbox, PC, and mobile (The Verge)](https://www.theverge.com/2017/9/20/16339242/minecraft-cross-platform-update-better-together-windows-10-pc-mobile-switch-xbox)
- [Minecraft gets Xbox Live: Console, PC, and mobile can play together (VentureBeat)](https://venturebeat.com/2016/06/13/minecraft-gets-xbox-live-console-pc-and-mobile-can-play-together/)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a disk game, you can play on the xbox 1S, but if it is online, I do not know. I believe that you could not unless it was not part of the Better Together update. This article explains it: [XBOX Minecraft support](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-titles/minecraft-better-together-update)